# What makes entered text be at a different height than the placeholder?

Tags: css

The input is only for the two decimals. The 12 is entered, and the 00 is a placeholder. Here the input has `vertical-align: text-bottom`

[image]

The `00` is too high. And here the input has `vertical-align: middle`

[image]

The `12` is too low.

When I change the font-size, the placeholder and entered text seem to have the same vertical alignment when small, but diverge when large:

http://g.recordit.co/bIRXWfdJ32.gif

Full code:

[image]:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can post a demo with editable code so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's an error with your link.

Comment: Fixed the link, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The black text is from the .input div. The grey is from the placeholder. You need to make sure that ".input" is styled the same as ".input > input"

```
.verify-deposits > .input,
.verify-deposits > .input > input {
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried that, no change. The `12` text entered into the `<input>`. Added gif of changing font-size.